# AWS Serverless DynamoDB Row Level Authorization With Cognito and Lambda Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, permissions, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Alright, so I currently have almost everything working by following this guide here and pieces of several others.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/

However, instead of giving users direct access to the DynamoDB, I am running it through an API Gateway and then a Lambda Function using an Authorization header and the Cognito session id.

I have that part working.

In my lambda function I call the update function

```
const data = await documentClient.update(params).promise();
```

I have AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole policy and the following policy added to my lambda function role to allow the row level access for Update

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:mydynamodbid:table/userdata"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

It works fine with the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess but I am not sure that is accomplishing what I am looking for as I think it just completely bypasses the condition.

I am getting the following error though

```
 "User: arn:aws:sts::**********:assumed-role/db-crud/update-user-info-by-id is not 
authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-
2:************:table/userdata"
```

Has anyone encountered anything like this or see where I am possibly going wrong?

This is the flow I am going for, and this is related to step 6
[image]

Comment: I checked the lambda function as well and I can see this under permissions 
arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:**********:table/users 
Allow: dynamodb:UpdateItem

Comment: Did you look at this post https://medium.com/@manojf/implementing-a-secure-backend-on-aws-e873cc7b03cb ?